# Keras: If my train data is in subfolders, my validation data needs to be too?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using `image_dataset_from_directory` to get my train data and this is working fine (my train data is inside subfolders). Now i want to load my test data (that is not in subfolders) but I can't manage to do it, I tried using `flow_from_directory` and this error shows up:

ValueError: Shapes (None, 41) and (None, 1) are incompatible

That's how I load my images:

```
ds_train = image_dataset_from_directory(
    'final_database',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'Spectograms/audio_test',
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=64,
)
```

My full code:

```
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

ds_train = image_dataset_from_directory(
    'final_database',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'Spectograms/audio_test',
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=64,
)

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, activation="relu", padding='same',
                  input_shape=[128, 128, 3]),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),

    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),

    layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),

    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(units=6, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    ds_train,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    epochs=40,
    verbose=0
)
```

Comment: The flow_from_directory method expects one sub-directory per class. You can try creating a folder inside 'audio_test' and place your images in that folder or you can give the directory path as 'spectogram' is you have the images inside the folder audio_test.

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work :(

Comment: Looks like the error can be from another part of your code. Are you using the loss as 'categorical_crossentropy'?

Comment: Yeah. Should I use another one? I'll edit the question with my full code

Comment: The number of units in the last dense layer depends on the type of classification problem.  I am assuming that yours is a multi class classification problem (more than 2 classes) in which case the number of units should be equal to the number of classes that you are trying to predict and the activation function that needs to be used is 'softmax'.  1 unit and the activation function 'sigmoid' is used in the last dense layer for binary classification problems (predicting one of 2 classes).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ImageDataGenerator,flow_from_directory for your validation images they must be seperated into class directories just as your training images were. Now you can partition your training data into a training st and a validation set with the code below:

```
v_split=.2 # set percentage of data to use for validation
ds_train = image_dataset_from_directory(
    'final_database',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    validation_split=v_split,
    subset='training,
    shuffle=True)
ds_valid=image_dataset_from_directory(
    'final_database',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    validation_split=v_split,
    subset='validation',
    shuffle=True)
```

now if you organize your test directory in the same manner as you did for the train directory then you can create a test set as follows (assuming your test directory is called final_database_test)

```
test_ds=image_dataset_from_directory(
    'final_database_test',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,    
    shuffle=False)
```

Comment: So it is a must for both train and test to have the same directory "architecture"? Is there any other function I can use so only my train data stays in subfolders?